# What is the best practice on sending emails from PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, email, plsql

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong):

The older package [utl_smtp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm) is very flexible and lets you send emails of any length. Once you open the connection, you can keep writing to it. However, it doesn't support multiple recipients in the same email - you have to send multiple emails.

The newer package [utl_mail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm) lets you send send an email with multiple recipients in the same email. But it doesn't allow you to send emails with a size greater than 32Kb.

How do you folks send email from the Oracle backend? Is there any way to send email from Oracle without either of these limitations?

EDIT: Thanks to Jeffrey Kemp I now know that the premise of the question is invalid. `UTL_SMTP` allows multiple recipients, so it is the obvious choice.

Comment: **utl_smtp** does not restrict the number of recipients - it's a complete implementation of the SMTP protocol, after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @[Jeffrey Kemp]. I see my mistake now. It should work if I write each recipient in the header.

Comment: You need to call RCPT for each recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use utl_smtp.

If you need something else you must create an external library that can be called from the oracle kernel.
This involves detail coding in languages like C/C++, and DBA help to set up.

Here is an overview of external procedure calls:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm

Answer (score 1):

utl_mail, for the simplicity.

If you have a large amount of content then it can go in an attachment.